# Using a unicode character in a .java file?

Tags: java, android, unicode

I want to set a unicode character in a class file like this:

```
TextView tv = ...;
tv.setText("·");
```

is there anything potentially wrong with using a unicode character in a .java file?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a pedantic comment, but the official [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) states "Programs are written in Unicode." I guess that would mean that you can't have a *non-Unicode character* in Java, whatever that would mean.  You might want to rephrase the question.  Terminology and naming are important in this business. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Java strings support Unicode so you shouldn't run into any problems. You might have to check that the `TextView` class handles all the Unicode characters (which it should), but Java itself will handle the unicode characters.

You should also ensure that the file is saved with the correct encoding settings. Essentially this means that your editor should save the java file as UTF-8 encoded Unicode. See the comments to this answer for more details on this.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the editor you are using will save the Java source in UTF-8 (which is what the compiler expects). In Eclipse, the easiest thing to do is navigate to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace, then set the text file encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: I'm always wondering why Eclipse set its default text file encoding according to the OS environment. IMO, IntelliJ has much better default settings overall.

Comment: @TedHopp Hmm, it won't understand UTF-16 (with BOMs) and such?

Comment: @pst The compiler can take any text file encodings, as long as you tell it explicitly, however, the strings in class files are encoded in UTF-8 if I remember it correctly.

Comment: @Oleksi: The comments above address the question, but your answer alone doesn't IMO.  The question asks about including a unicode character in a *Java source file* -- which requires that the file be saved in an appropriate encoding and the javac compiler told to read the file in said encoding.

Comment: @GregKopff Yes, I've updated the answer to talk about saving the file as well.

Answer (score 3):

> **Is there anything potentially wrong with using a unicode character in a .java file?**

As you know, Strings within the JVM are stored as Unicode - so the question is how to deal with Unicode in *Java source files* ...

In short, using Unicode is fine.  There are a few ways to approach it ...

By default, the [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) compiler expects the source file to be in the platform default encoding.  This can be overridden using the `-encoding` flag:

> `-encoding encoding` 
>                 Sets    the    source    file    encoding    name,    such    as
>                 EUCJIS/SJIS/ISO8859-1/UTF8.  If `-encoding` is not specified,  the
>                 platform default converter is used.

Alternatively, if it's a single character (like it appears to be), you can keep your source file in your platform default encoding, and specify the character using the Unicode escape sequence:

```
tv.setText("\u1234");
```

... where '1234' is the Unicode value for the character you want.

Another alternative is to first save your file in your Unicode-compatible encoding (say UTF-8), then use [`native2ascii`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) to convert that file to your native encoding (it will convert any out of range characters to the corresponding Unicode escape sequence).

> NAME 
>        `native2ascii` - native to ASCII converter
>
> SYNOPSIS 
>         `native2ascii [ options ] [ inputfile [outputfile]]`
>
> DESCRIPTION 
>         The Java compiler and other Java tools can only process files that contain  Latin-1  or   Unicode-encoded   (`\udddd`   notation)   characters.
>         native2ascii  converts files that contain other character encoding into
>         files containing Latin-1 or Unicode-encoded charaters.
>
> If outputfile is omitted, standard output is used for output.  In addition, if inputfile is omitted, standard input is used for input.